# Is it possible to have multiple instances of iAds?

Tags: iphone, ios, iad

This is not for multiple iAds displayed on one screen.

I have two views, both capable of displaying iAds.  I want each view to have a `ADBannerView` instance.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't get rejected for using multiple `ADBannerview`s, as user635633 says.

But keep in mind that using more than one is not recommended by Apple in [iAd Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html) (see section *Banner View Best Practices*).

> Instead, your application should
>   create a single banner view and use it
>   throughout your user interface. As the
>   user navigates around your
>   application, your application moves
>   the banner view onto any screen that
>   is expected to display a banner.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that.  One of my apps has 2 views, and they both have iad banners in them.  It was approved without problem from Apple.

Comment: Thank you. Does this cause a problem with you transition to a new view? I.e. does the ad view have to get a new ad from the iAd server?  or is it cleaver enough to re-use the ad without putting pressure on the network?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not just transfer the ad.  It will call the server and load a new ad.  Sometimes it loads the same ad which provides a seamless user experience, but other time it doesn’t.  The transition is also not always smooth.  Sometimes it takes a second or two for the new ad to load.

Comment: But thats not necessarily a bad thing.  You get the same amount of money if the ad shows for 2 seconds, or 20.  But if a new ad loads, thats 2 ad views instead of one

Comment: Would it be possible in a single controller app to display two fixed banners, one on top and one at the bottom? While testing one of the banners is always blank while the other displays the test iAd banner.

Comment: No, that's not allowed. You can only have one banner on a single view. That will cause an automatic rejection.