# Add multiple AdBannerViewDelegates

Tags: objective-c, banner, iad

I have made a quick iad test app for ipad and it works great. I just have one quick question. How do I add multiple ad banners? There is currently only one and I was just wondering if it was possible to add multiple ones to my program. Also, If there are multiple ones, will they all show the same ad, or will they show different ones? Thanks for your help!

here is my current h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate>

@end
```

and my current m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark iAd Delegate Methods

-(void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    [banner setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
} 

-(void) bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0];
    [banner setAlpha:0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

@end
```

Comment: Because that's just what I need on my iOS device, more ads.

Comment: Not helping. Please I really need an answer for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple instances of iAds?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273221/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-instances-of-iads)